# CSS Media Queries not matching max / min widths precisely

Tags: css, media-queries

Here is the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 971px) and (max-width : 1224px) {
    main #titlebox{
        height: 300px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 785px) and (max-width : 970px) {
    main #titlebox{
        height: 250px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 784px) {
    main #titlebox{
        height: 225px;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when resizing the browser, the the media queries are not applied when expected.  For example, starting with the browser very wide (> 1300px) and then slowly decreasing the width of the browser, the first media query doesn't get applied until the  element is approx. 1209px wide.  I would expect that it would apply as soon as the width became 1224px. Likewise, the next one isn't applied until Approx 955px not 970px, and so on. I have tested this behavior in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: I tested using your CSS in Chrome, measuring the width with the develop tools opened. It functions at the right widths. What are you using to measure the width?

Comment: Did you account for the 20px scroll bar?

Comment: Ugh. no. I didn't realize that the scrollbar was included.  That makes is very difficult to be precise because different browsers have different scrollbar widths.  CSS makes me crazy.

Comment: I've seen some attempts to address this if it's critical for you. I usually just deal with it. Found this library https://github.com/stowball/mqGenie. Could help. Talks about taking the scrollbar into account for the viewport to give you a "true" breakpoint

Comment: @salniro That's actually nowhere 20px, more like 13px or so.

Answer (score 12):

Check your zoom-level in your browser.
In Firefox your zoom-level affects your webpage but not the displayed screen sizes in the dev-tools.

Comment: Sometimes we miss the smallest things. Good to have a helpful nudge in such cases. Thank you.